# How do I create an instance of a generic type with a parameter of type list

Tags: c#, list, generics, reflection

I have a generic class `Result` that looks like this

```
public class Result<T>
{
    public List<Error> Errors { get; set; } = new List<Error>();

    public T ResultObject { get; set; }

    public Result(List<Error> errors)
    {
        Errors = errors;
        Success = false;
    }
}
```

I try to create an instance like this:

```
public Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
{
    var context = new ValidationContext<TRequest>(request);

    var failures = _validators
        .Select(v => v.Validate(context))
        .SelectMany(result => result.Errors)
        .Where(f => f != null)
        .ToList();

    if (failures.Count != 0)
    {
        var responseType = typeof(TResponse);
        // This is the important line
        return Task.FromResult(Activator.CreateInstance(responseType, new object[] { failures.Select(x => new Error(x.ErrorMessage)).ToList() }) as TResponse);
    }

    return next();
}
```

`TResponse` is of type `Result<GetUserFlow>`. `GetUserFlow` is a dto but not important in this case. When I run my code I get the following error:

> System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type
> 'Heimdall.Application.Result`1[[Heimdall.Application.Dtos.GetUserFlow,
> Heimdall.Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]]' not found.

I guess the problem is that when passing a list as parameter it isn't seen as one parameter but as many. Each created Error is one parameter. I couldn't find anything about this topic.

Comment: You aren't creating a type of `Result<T>`, you are creating a type of `TResponse`.

Comment: Where does `TResponse` come in

Comment: @Neil I updated my question

Comment: What happens if you try `responseType.GetConstructors()[0].Invoke(new object[] { ...`? By the way, you may find the factory pattern much easier: pass through to `Handle` function a factory delegate `Func<List<Errors>, TResponse>` and use that delegate to call the constructor. So `var result = Handle(..., errors => new Result<GetUserFlow>(errors));` or something like that

Comment: Which one worked?

Comment: @Charlieface `return Task.FromResult(responseType.GetConstructors()[1].Invoke(new object[] { param }) as TResponse);` I had multiple constructors, thus the 1

Comment: I do suggest you use the factory pattern though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can invoke the correct constructor with:**

```cs
constructorInfo.Invoke(new object[] { failures.Select(x => new Error(x.ErrorMessage)).ToList() }) as TResponse
```

To get the constructor, use somthing like this:

```cs
responseType.GetConstructors()[0]
// if you have multiple constructors, ensure the correct one with:
responseType.GetConstructor(new Type[]{ typeof(List<Error>) })
```

---

**By the way, you may find the factory pattern much easier.**

Pass through to the Handle function a factory delegate `Func<List<Errors>, TResponse>` and use that delegate to call the constructor.

```cs
public Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
  RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next, Func<List<Errors>, TResponse> responseCreator)
{
....
    return Task.FromResult(responseCreator(
        failures.Select(x => new Error(x.ErrorMessage)).ToList()
    ));
....
}
```

You call it like this:

```cs
 var result = Handle(...., errors => new Result<GetUserFlow>(errors));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I can't implement your approach. I am using Mediatr and the seen code is an implemented interface from IPipelineBehavior. So I can't add additional parameters to the method.

Comment: And out of curiosity, do you happen to know why Activator.CreateInstance doesn't work?